# How do I combine an anchor tag AND a passed variable in an HTML HREF?

Tags: html, anchor, href

Say I have an anchor somewhere on a different page:

```
<A NAME="blah">
```

On the page I'm currently on, I want to go that that anchor on that different page while also passing a GET parameter, such as, for example:

```
<A HREF="otherpage.htm#blah?data=1234">Good Stuff!</A>
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me.  It loads the page and passes the variable but doesn't go to the anchor.  I've searched for examples on the anchor tag, and there's tons of them, but nobody talks about jumping to an anchor in a page while also passing parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The bookmark always goes last.

```
<A HREF="otherpage.htm?data=1234#blah">Good Stuff!</A>
```

Comment: Man I've been doing websites since like forever and I was today years old when I learned this. Thanks