# Linking to an HTML anchor on a page with AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, url, get, anchor

I am having an issue when trying to link to a part of a page using an html anchor. The issue is that the page I am linking to has several AJAX calls that take time to complete. This  stops me from linking to the anchor.

```
<a href="domain.com/view?id=<?=$article['id']?>#anchor">
```

should link to the comments section on my view page

```
//Non ajax content
<a id="anchor"></a>
<?php $this->widget('application.components.DisqusWidget', array('article' => $id));?> //The offending AJAX
```

If I go to domain.com/view?id=123, let it load, then append `#anchor` to the URL it takes me to the appropriate section. But `domain.com/view?id=123#anchor` only takes me to the top. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: have you tried to place the fragement in front of the parameters (ie. `domain.com/view#anchor?id=123` )? alternatively, inject a parameter separator (`&`): `domain.com/view?id=123&#anchor`. Using Javascript/JQuery you could also navigate to the anchor in a ready/onLoad handler.

Comment: AFAIK @BParks is using the right syntax for a url with get parameters and an anchor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158283/how-do-i-combine-an-anchor-tag-and-a-pased-variable-in-an-html-href

Comment: can you post a link to the web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your Disqus widget appends data on the bottom of your page.
Only then is your page long enough to actually scroll to your anchor.

One way to solve your problem would be to attach a JavaScript handler (callback) to the load function of your comment section which would be triggered as soon as the AJAX requests are finished.
In that callback function you can trigger the scroll to your anchor like this:

```
window.location.hash = '#anchor';
```

Answer (score 1):

On your Ajax callback, you could add

```
    location.href=location.hash;
```

so it will jump after the ajax call finishes.