# How do I jump to an anchor in a page as soon as it opens without user clicking anything

Tags: php, html, url, header, anchor

I want a webpage to jump to an anchor point as soon as the page is opened without the user having to click on anything.  But when I jump to the anchor point the GET method is skipped so $s doesn't have a value.

```
    <a href="www.mysite.com/page.php#anchor?s=1">
```

and on page

```
    <?php 
    $s=$_GET['s'];
    echo"<a id="anchor"></a>Page $s"
    ?>
```

Comment: <a> href requires user click to jump to another website.for this you will need javascript.

Comment: His link is messed up so he prob' means no additional click after page loading.

Answer (score 0):

I **know** that `Javascript` is **not** in your *question tags*, but there is **no** way to do this without it.
Your document code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("www.mysite.com/page.php?s=1")
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is an `onload` *function* that will be called when the page *loads*. When it will called it will **redirect** you to your another **webpage**.

Your `php` file code:

```
 <?php 
    $s=$_GET['s'];
    echo"<a id="anchor"></a>Page $s"
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark goes last:

`page.php?s=1#anchor`

[How do I combine an anchor tag AND a passed variable in an HTML HREF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158283/how-do-i-combine-an-anchor-tag-and-a-passed-variable-in-an-html-href)